# How to get value from bootstrap modal using jQuery in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating lookup page in ASP.NET MVC 5 to search value based on some criteria. I have been able to pass value (criteria) from page to bootstrap modal. When list of data is displayed in modal (as shown in picture below)

[image]

if user click select link icon then FirmMatterID (Hidden Field),  FirmMatterNo and Description value will be passed to the page. How to solve this?

Code to show the bootstrap modal:

```
@model ViewModels.InvoiceViewModel

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="lookup-timekeeper-container">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Invoice", FormMethod.Post, new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        ...
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirmMatter.FirmMatterNo, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="form-inline">
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.FirmMatterID)
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirmMatter.FirmMatterNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnLookupFirmMatter" data-id="@Model.SubsidiaryClientID" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                        Lookup Firm Matter
                    </button>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirmMatterID)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirmMatter.Description, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirmMatter.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })
            </div>
        </div>
        ...
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnLookupFirmMatter").click(function () {
                var url = '@Url.Content("~/Invoice/LookupFirmMatter/")' + $("#SubsidiaryClientID").val();
                $.get(url)
                    .done(function (data) {
                        if (!data.message) {
                            $("#lookup-timekeeper-container").html(data);
                            $("#myModal").modal(show = true, backdrop = true);
                        } 
                    });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult LookupFirmMatter(int? id = null)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return Json(new { message = "Please select subsidiary client" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    var subsidiaryClient = db.SubsidiaryClients.SingleOrDefault(sc => sc.SubsidiaryClientID == id);

    if (subsidiaryClient == null)
    {
        return Json(new { message = "Subsidiary Client ID not found"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    var firmMatters = db.LookupFirmMatters.Where(lfm => lfm.SubsidiaryClientNo == subsidiaryClient.SubsidiaryClientNo).ToList();

    return PartialView("_LookupFirmMatter", firmMatters);
}
```

PartialView:

```
@model List<Models.LookupFirmMatter>

<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Firm's Matter No</th>
            <th>Description</th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td><a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></a></td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirmMatterNo)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirmMatterDescription)</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

Based On @ChintanaMeegamarachchi I added `copyToFrom` on View:

```
function copyToForm(firmMatterNo, description){
    $formRef = $('#form1');
    $formRef.find('#FirmMatterID').val(firmMatterId);
    $formRef.find('#FirmMatterNo').val(firmMatterNo);
    $formRef.find('#Description').val(description);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume markup for the lookup modal is passed via ‘data’ parameter in success callback of ajax call.

For each row, why not implement an event handel for onClick for the select button to copy the filed values to the hidden form filed,

***Pseudo code***

```
function copyToForm(firmMatterId, firmMatterNo, description){
    $formRef = $(‘#id-of-form’);
    $formRef.find(‘#id-of- firmMatterId’).val(firmMatterId);
    $formRef.find(‘#id-of- firmMatterNo).val(firmMatterNo);
    $formRef.find(‘#id-of- description).val(description);
}
```

And now you can render each row in your partial view for the model (what you send our as a result of the ajax call) with something like `onclick = copyToForm(row.firmMatterId, row.firmMatterNo, row.description)`

Hope this helps

Comment: It doesn't work, I've added onclick function on `<tr>`:
`<tr onclick="javascript:copyToForm(@item.FirmMatterNo, @item.FirmMatterDescription)">`. I've updated the question to add the partial view code.

Comment: Do you see any errors on the console? Could you move the onclick code to anchor element (the button)

Comment: And add quots around FirmMatterDescription. ex copyToForm(@item.FirmMatterNo, ‘@item.FirmMatterDescription’)

Comment: I move `copyToForm` to link control: 
`<td><a href="javascript:copyToForm('@item.FirmMatterNo', '@item.FirmMatterDescription')" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></a></td>` and see F12-console there is an error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" when click the link. See the update.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was to move the whole onclick like
<td><a href=”#” onclick="javascript:copyToForm('@item.FirmMatterNo', '@item.FirmMatterDescription')" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></a></td>